# ESP wireless interfaces - master thesis measurements

Tags: networking, esp32, emc

I have a question regarding ESP32 wireless interfaces.
Long story short I gotta do master research and I'd like it to be about ESP32 Wi-Fi + BL/BLE. My supervisor suggested we could make use of EMC chamber available on my department building and measure how well ESP deals with electromagnetic interference during transmission (ESP to ESP via Wi-Fi, BL, and BLE as I mentioned).
The problem is that we gotta make it dependent on some changeable parameter. First, I thought about using various protocols but in longer run, it doesn't make sense. Then my supervisor suggested changing for example MTU. I did a search and found how to change it for BL but can't find how it can be done for Wi-Fi.
Does someone have any idea how to modify MTU for Wi-Fi in ESP and what else I could change to influence electromagnetic resistance anyhow?

Is it a reasonable subject?
Maybe as a society that knows ESP well, you can propose some other interesting idea for research?

Thanks for the time and effort!

Comment: What is MPU? I'm not aware of any use of this acronym which fits this context.

Comment: Maximum transmission unit ;-) Simply the biggest chunk of data that can be send at once by the hardware.

Edit: Just noticed typo in my question. Fixing.

Comment: I would bet on tweaking tx power, phy rate and retransmit interval for WiFi. Espressif does not provide users with source code for the phy for a good reason so it could be limiting factor for your research. Keep in mind built-in adaptive frequency hopping feature of BLE prior making any conclusions regarding tweaks to MTU in BLE.